# When exactly is onContentPrepareData triggered?

Tags: plugin, plugin-events

According to https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content, it is `Called after the data for a JForm has been retrieved.` It is not very clear when exactly the event is triggered.
Based on the documentation, I'd thought it is triggered after users click the submit button of a form and before the data of the form is actually submitted. But it doesn't seem so in reality.

To test it, I enabled the user-profile plugin, and in its `profile.php` file, I put a `var_dump` in the `onContentPrepareData` function

```
    public function onContentPrepareData($context, $data)
    {
        var_dump($data);
        // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
        if (!in_array($context, array('com_users.profile', 'com_users.user', 'com_users.registration', 'com_admin.profile')))
        {
            return true;
        }
...
```

If my guess was right, when I open the editing page of a user's profile, this `var_dump` will only trigger after users click 'submit" button. But actually the output of `var_dump` is displayed when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

It's triggered whenever data is loaded into a form. And that normally happens whenever a form is loaded.

When you open the profile edit page, it has a form loaded with data loaded into. If the event was not triggered, the fields added by plugins would not be populated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you specify what is "whenever data is loaded into a form"? I understand "If the event was not triggered, the fields added by plugins would not be populated." What I don't understand is why forms need to be "loaded with data". For profile editing form, it must load data for users to edit, this I understand, but I can't think of other occurrences where forms need to load data. Can you please give me some other example where forms need to be loaded with data? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make this any more clear than it already is. Hopefully someone else can explain.